# how to use UriComponentsBuilder for replacing pathsegment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, uri, uribuilder

I have a url as below

```
http://example.com/{id}
```

I want to change it to

```
http://example.com/12
```

I have coded as below

```
url= "http://example.com/{id}";

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);
builder.pathSegment("{id}", "12");
UriComponents uriComponents = builder.build().encode();
URI uri = uriComponents.toUri();

System.out.println(uri);
```

Its giving me output as

```
http://example.com/%7Bid%7D/id/12
```

Not sure what is right way to use UriComponentsBuilder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace placeholder with a real value, you need to call `build` with parameters

```java
    String url = "http://example.com/{id}";

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url);
    URI uri = builder.build("12");

    System.out.println(uri);
```